# Matrix COUNT + GROUP BY in python

Tags: python, matrix

I have a matrix of vectors filled with integers. For example:

```
[[1, 2, 3],
 [2, 3, 1],
 [1, 2, 3],
 [2, 3, 1],
 [2, 3, 1]]
```

and I want to count all distinguish vectors in order to obtain something like this:

```
[[2, [1, 2, 3]],
 [3, [2, 3, 1]]]
```

where first I have the number of number of occurrences and then the vector.

In SQL it can be done with COUNT + GROUP BY.

However, how can I 'smartly' compute it with python?

Comment: What do you mean by "smartly"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Python only, you can use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects):

```
from collections import Counter

matrix = [[1, 2, 3],
          [2, 3, 1],
          [1, 2, 3],
          [2, 3, 1],
          [2, 3, 1]]
c = Counter(map(tuple, matrix))
result = [[count, list(row)] for row, count in c.items()]
print(result)
# [[2, [1, 2, 3]], [3, [2, 3, 1]]]
```

With NumPy, you can use [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html):

```
import numpy as np

matrix = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
                   [2, 3, 1],
                   [1, 2, 3],
                   [2, 3, 1],
                   [2, 3, 1]])
rows, counts = np.unique(matrix, axis=0, return_counts=True)
result = [[count, list(row)] for row, count in zip(rows, counts)]
print(result)
# [[2, [1, 2, 3]], [3, [2, 3, 1]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

First convert every sub-list of m to tuple. Then use `collections.Counter` to count the occurances of the tuple in the main list. Now loop through this counter object with keys (no of counts) and values (tuples) and append them into a new list like this :

```
from collections import Counter
m = [[1, 2, 3],
 [2, 3, 1],
 [1, 2, 3],
 [2, 3, 1],
 [2, 3, 1]]
m = map(tuple, m)
l = []
for k,v in Counter(m).items():
    l.append([v, list(k)])
```

**Output** :

```
[[2, [1, 2, 3]], [3, [2, 3, 1]]]
```

Note : `Counter(m)` produces this counter object :

```
Counter({(2, 3, 1): 3, (1, 2, 3): 2})
```